# Alert changes in agents' state (tools, tips, etc.)

Tags: database, pipeline, alert, detection

*My Problem*

- We are monitoring a network with many agents (let's say 3 million agents). We receive information about agents when they experience some events.
- Consider that each time an event occurs we received the following information (among others):

  - agent's ID
  - timestamp of the event
  - state (with some ID, e.g., *state_1*, *state_2*, ..., *state_n*)
- This information is currently stored on a database.
- An agent may change its state variable, for example going from *state_1* to *state_2*.

**We are interested in send a notification each time an agent changes its state variable. The detection of the change may be performed in a online fashion, meaning, upon reception of new information.**

*Some of my ideas*
My idea is to build some kind of 'pipeline' where everytime new information about an agent is received, there's some kind of lookup stage, where I check the previous information about the agent (using its ID) and alert if the state changed.

We've previously used Elasticsearch as a storage option; however this tool doesn't seems to fit the problem.

*Question*
I do not know where to start, or which tools may be useful to address this problem. I think the idea of using a pipeline might be in the right track, however I'm not sure how to build it.

If you could give me some insights regarding some possible approaches, tools or others that I could explore I'd really appreciate it.

Best regards,